# Как избежать двойных кавычек в тексте json

Tags: python

мне нужно взять текст из файла json и сделать из него python объект. Проблема в том, что в тексте могут встречаться не экранированные кавычки, как я могу это исправить?(Просьба не говорить, что этот json не валидный, я и сам знаю, но нужно как-то работать с таким)

Скрипт:

```
import json

with open("test.txt", encoding='utf-8') as reader:
    print(reader.read())
    print(json.loads(reader.read()))
```

Файл json(просто демо и в оригинальном намного больше раз встречается эта проблема, поэтому надо их заменить все сразу):

```
{"test_key": "Its like "test" vcuubgyhh"}
```

Comment: где вы такие json берете?

Comment: Честно говоря это всё 1 задача, просто я потихоньку пытаюсь его распарсить, и вылезают новые ошибки

Comment: посмотрите. https://qna.habr.com/q/638358  там код на php, нл проблема прям ваша

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Мне кажется, вам с этими заморочками проще свой парсер написать, например типа https://habr.com/ru/post/309242/ может, в сети найдете и для 3

Comment: `{"a": "b", "c": "d"}` - это словарь с двумя ключами: `'a' -> 'b'`, `'c' -> 'd'`? Или это словарь с одним ключом `'a' -> 'b", "c": "d'`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy безусловно, почти всегда это не однозначно. особенно. если допустить, что неэкранированная кавычка может быть и одна. А если в строке встречаются еще и символы, закрывающие массив или объект (]})... То есть парсер должен идти до ситуации ошибки и брать другой вариант. в общем, непростая задача

Comment: Если задача не велика по размеру (число кавычек мало), то перебираете подмножества кавычек, экранируете их, разбираете парсером. Через экспоненциальное время у вас на руках все возможные корректные разборы. Из них можно отобрать наиболее осмысленный вариант. Чтобы понять, можно ли так действовать и как сократить поиск, надо иметь больше информации о задаче.

Comment: Я посмотрел разбираемый файл. ТС сперва процедурой `singleToDouble` создаёт конфликт, затем просит нас его исправить. Уважаемый TC, не надо плодить задачи, возьмите несколько примеров текстов которые вы хотите разобрать и задайте отдельный вопрос: "вот пример, как мне его запихнуть в Питон?". Эта задаче решается куда легче, чем борьба с кавычками.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял Вашу логику, то примерно так можно. Посмотрите, может, что-то возьмете для себя:

```
txt = "\"test_key\": \"Its like \"test\" vcuubgyhh\""
print(txt)   # Иммитация Вашей строки в текстовом документе: "test_key": "Its like "test" vcuubgyhh"

lst_split = txt.split('":')
dictJs = {}

for i, value in enumerate(lst_split):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        key = lst_split[i][1:]
    else:
        dictJs[key]=lst_split[i][2:-1]  # берем со 2го индекса, т.к. 0 - это пробел, 1ый - это кавычки. Последний не берем, т.к. там тоже кавычки в строке

print(dictJs)    # Выведет: {'test_key': 'Its like "test" vcuubgyhh'}
```

Логика проста. Сплитим по 2ум знакам: ***":*** четные элементы - это ключи, нечетные - это значения ключей.

Answer (score 0):

Пока нет дополнительной информации о джейсонах для разбора, вот самое общее (и самое медленное) решение: вырезаем из строки все кавычки, часть экранируем, собираем строку обратно, разбираем парсером. В случае успешного разбора публикуем вариант.

Это медленно и не понятно как выбирать из всех вариантов нужный. Чтобы превратить этот код в рабочее решение, надо больше данных: как выглядит типичный джейсон? могут ли быть кавычки в ключах? это произвольный джейсон или именно словарь с одним уровнем? много ли в словаре ключей?

```
import itertools
import json


def parse(json_text):
    parts = json_text.split('"')
    for q in itertools.product(('"', r'\"'), repeat=len(parts) - 1):
        t = ''.join(s for pair in zip(parts, q + ('', )) for s in pair)
        try:
            yield json.loads(t)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            pass
    

print(*parse('{"test_key": "Its like "test" vcuubgyhh"}'), sep='\n')
print(*parse('{"a": "b", "c": "d"}'), sep='\n')
```

> ```
> $ python parse.py
> {'test_key': 'Its like "test" vcuubgyhh'}
> {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
> {'a': 'b", "c": "d'}
> {'a": "b", "c': 'd'}
> ```

**P.S.** Ваш пример кода не работает совсем. Вы его тестировали?